# PHP - How to add an tag to the second tag, and after the last tag?

Tags: php, text

How to add an tag **< div >** to the second tag **< p >**, and after the last tag **< /p >**? (PHP) 
For example:

```
<p>text... short text - first</p>
<p>text, text, text, text... - Second</p>
<p>text, text, text, text... - Third</p>
<p>text, text, text, text... - Fourth</p> 
....       <-- some texts
```

To:

```
<p>text... short text - first</p>
<div class="long-text">                             <-- add tag '<div ...>'
   <p>text, text, text, text... - Second</p>
   <p>text, text, text, text... - Third</p>
   <p>text, text, text, text... - Fourth</p>
   ....       <-- some texts
</div>                                              <-- close tag '</div>'
```

Comment: to start, those are called "tags", and attribute would be <div **id='asdf'** >text</div> (the things in bold are attributes)

Comment: Oops, I forgot. Correcting my question. thank you

Comment: I think you'll be waiting a long time for an answer with an unclear question. Please update your question to be more clear. Are you generating from an database? Are you just trying to add those divs with PHP tags?

Comment: I do not really asked a question. Help, you can fix this question, please. You got that question

Comment: @Areku_UA "I do not really asked a question." That is the problem on a Q&A platform. See: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: feeela - I saw in the page. Excuse me, where's the help text?
I know how little English.

Comment: user1048676 - Yes, the output text from the database. And simply add these divas with PHP tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right approach would be using dom documents: There's some sample code, hope it helps you to understand how DOMDocuments work, for more info go to the php documentation:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.dom.php

Code:

```
$str = '<p>text... short text - first</p>
<p>text, text, text, text... - Second</p>
<p>text, text, text, text... - Third</p>
<p>text, text, text, text... - Fourth</p>';


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom -> loadHTML($str);
$dom->formatOutput = true;

//referencing and setting the needed elements
$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
$p_list = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
$div = $dom->createElement('div');
$div->setAttribute('class', 'long-text');

$length = $p_list->length;
//moving the p's to the created $div element
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
    if($i == 0)continue;
    $item = $p_list->item(1);
    $div->appendChild($item);
}

//appending the filled up $div to the body
$body->appendChild($div);

//output
$string = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $string;
```